# XSL Calling a Template that Sums

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to loop through items, dedupe those items, sum up their value, and display that sum.

I'm new to xsl and have a good base going but cannot get the summed value to pull in.

Any help with this would be awesome. Currently, i need to pull the template value in where I am pulling in the $totalvalue variable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl"> <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />


    <xsl:variable name="totalValue">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[not(Prop[@prop_name = 'imageurl']/@val = following::Prop[@prop_name = 'imageurl']/@val)]">
            <n><xsl:value-of select="Prop[@prop_name = 'tradeval']/@val"/></n>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>    <xsl:template match="/">
     <span style='color:#cf181e'>   You Have <xsl:value-of select="count(//*[Prop[@prop_name = 'tradeval']/@val and not(Prop[@prop_name = 'imageurl']/@val = preceding::Prop[@prop_name = 'imageurl']/@val)])" />    Things Worth $   <xsl:value-of select="$totalValue" />   </span> </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <sum>
            <xsl:copy-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($totalValue)/n)"/>
        </sum>
    </xsl:template>    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The supplied xml will be formatted as:

```
<Msg>
  <Props>
    <transactionline_to_customers>
      <transactionline_to_customer>
        <Prop entity_id="117" pk_id="103009" prop_id="10152" prop_name="transactionline_to_productsku.sku" type_id="20" encrypt_flag="0" val="119893" />
        <Prop entity_id="117" pk_id="103009" prop_id="10253" prop_name="transactionline_to_productsku.tradeval" type_id="40" encrypt_flag="0" val="20.0000" />
        <Prop entity_id="117" pk_id="103009" prop_id="10254" prop_name="transactionline_to_productsku.imageurl" type_id="25" encrypt_flag="0" val="http://www.google.com/common/images/1193b.jpg" />
        <transactionline_to_productsku>
          <Prop entity_id="117" pk_id="103009" prop_id="10254" prop_name="imageurl" type_id="25" encrypt_flag="0" val="http://www.google.com/common/images/1193b.jpg" />
          <Prop entity_id="117" pk_id="103009" prop_id="10253" prop_name="tradeval" type_id="40" encrypt_flag="0" val="20.0000" />
          <Prop entity_id="117" pk_id="103009" prop_id="10152" prop_name="sku" type_id="20" encrypt_flag="0" val="119893" />
        </transactionline_to_productsku>
      </transactionline_to_customer>
    </transactionline_to_customers>
    <resdetail_to_customers>
      <resdetail_to_customer>
        <Prop entity_id="117" pk_id="96699" prop_id="10152" prop_name="resdetail_to_prodsku.sku" type_id="20" encrypt_flag="0" val="113573" />
        <Prop entity_id="117" pk_id="96699" prop_id="10253" prop_name="resdetail_to_prodsku.tradeval" type_id="40" encrypt_flag="0" val="20.0000" />
        <Prop entity_id="117" pk_id="96699" prop_id="10254" prop_name="resdetail_to_prodsku.imageurl" type_id="25" encrypt_flag="0" val="http://www.google.com/common/images/1173b.jpg" />
        <resdetail_to_prodsku>
          <Prop entity_id="117" pk_id="96699" prop_id="10152" prop_name="sku" type_id="20" encrypt_flag="0" val="113573" />
          <Prop entity_id="117" pk_id="96699" prop_id="10253" prop_name="tradeval" type_id="40" encrypt_flag="0" val="20.0000" />
          <Prop entity_id="117" pk_id="96699" prop_id="10254" prop_name="imageurl" type_id="25" encrypt_flag="0" val="http://www.google.com/common/images/1173b.jpg" />
        </resdetail_to_prodsku>
      </resdetail_to_customer>
    </resdetail_to_customers>
  </Props>
</Msg>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post an example of your input and the expected output - see: [mcve].

Comment: @michael.hor257k Expected output should just read: "You have ## things worth $##"

Comment: I am afraid this is still cryptic. Please explain in words which values you want to include in your sum (I am assuming those are the same values you want to be counted, too).

Comment: @michael.hor257k i'm trying to dedupe records based off of the imageurl. then i need to count distinct imageurls, and sum up the tradeval for those distinct image urls. also, i'm on xsl 1.0. when the output reads: "you have ## things worth $##" my first ## is the count of the deduped imageurls, then the second ## is the sum of the tradeval for those deduped imageurls. i hope this helps!! thanks for taking a look.

Comment: It looks like you need to read up on a technique called Muenchian Grouping, as I think that will be your friend here; http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html. Do note in your input XML sample you have only one `Prop` element with a `prop_name` of "imageurl". Did you also want to include elements with "mwt_imageurl", for example, as well, in your de-duping? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC Thanks, I've tried incorporating that into this already and got stuck too. Also, i fixed the xml to make a little more sense. thanks!

Comment: I see only two `Prop[@prop_name = 'tradeval']` nodes in your input, and each of these seems to be associated with a different `@imageurl` - so I don't see what is there to dedupe. I suggest you provide step-by-step instructions how one would do this task manually, otherwise this is purely guesswork (which I am not willing to engage in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Muenchian grouping, if you want to get distinct "imageurl", you would first define a key like so:

```
 <xsl:key name="prop" match="Prop[@prop_name = 'imageurl']" use="@val" />
```

Then, the expression to get the distinct ones (or rather, the `Prop` elements with the first occurrence of each possible `@val`), it would be like this

```
 <xsl:variable name="distinct" select="//Prop[@prop_name = 'imageurl'][generate-id() = generate-id(key('prop', @val)[1])]" />
```

You can then use this node set to either get a count, or a sum of the adjacent "tradeval" elements.

Try this XSLT as an example

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:key name="prop" match="Prop[@prop_name = 'imageurl']" use="@val" />

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="distinct" select="//Prop[@prop_name = 'imageurl'][generate-id() = generate-id(key('prop', @val)[1])]" />
     <xsl:text>You have </xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="count($distinct)" />
     <xsl:text> distinct imageurl with with a tradeval sum of </xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="sum($distinct/../Prop[@prop_name = 'tradeval']/@val)" />
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: that did it! makes sense now that i see it all laid out. thanks!